# Take a screenshot from camera problem

Tags: unity, screenshot

I use script below to take a screenshot from camera. It's working fine. However, when I take a screenshot again (pressing k multiple times), its old image is not clear from the memory and it keep drawing over same image over and over again. If object is moving while taking screenshot multiple times, image I will get all frame combine into one image with every frame in the same image. What should I do to fix this problem?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HiResScreenShots : MonoBehaviour {
    public int resWidth = 2550; 
    public int resHeight = 3300;

    private bool takeHiResShot = true;

    public static string ScreenShotName(int width, int height) {
        return string.Format("{0}/screenshots/screen_{1}x{2}_{3}.png", 
                             Application.dataPath, 
                             width, height, 
                             System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
    }

    public void TakeHiResShot() {
        takeHiResShot = true;
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        takeHiResShot |= Input.GetKeyDown("k");
        if (takeHiResShot) {
            RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
            camera.targetTexture = rt;
            Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
            camera.Render();
            RenderTexture.active = rt;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
            camera.targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null; // JC: added to avoid errors
            Destroy(rt);
            byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
            takeHiResShot = false;
            Debug.Log("Capture!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like it's fixed after I set Camera "Clear Flags" to "Skybox"